# MVC - Spring Boot and Angular - What is the View in Spring?

Tags: java, angular, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I created a web application using Spring Boot for Backend and Angular 8 for Frontend with the help of the JHipster framework. The frontend communicates with the backend using a REST API.

I know that both Spring and Angular use of the MVC model. As such, in the case of Spring :

- the database, JPA classes, and repositories are the **Model**
- the REST Controllers are the **Controller**

My question is: what is the **View** part in the Spring application? My guess is that the entire Angular application takes the role of the view. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

The view part in Spring was popular due to the Spring MVC concept where the **view** comprised of **JSP (Dynamic)** and **HTML (Static)** pages.

As you rightly said Spring and Angular both are MVC based frameworks, but now the current trend is moving towards Microservices architecture instead of Monololithic architecture.
Microservices architecture is language independent for its operation and communicates using REST services.

Currently, the focus is on **separation of concerns** and how quickly the code can be delivered.

*1. Angular framework handles the UI part*

*2. Spring framework handles the backend operations (Business logics, interactions with the database and other servers.*

In spring framework the MVC means

1. Model - The class that carries data
2. View -The view page (JSP/HTML)
3. Controller - The class that manages the operation

As you said on the post *The database, JPA classes, and repositories are the Model* these are nothing but the repository pattern which is integrated with the MVC pattern to communicate with the database.

Answer (score 0):

To start Angular does not use MVC, Angular uses MVVM (model-view-view-model) or MVW (model-view-whatever)

Secondly your backend uses the n-layer pattern

Service Layer: Implement business logic

Data Access Objects: These are abstractions that your service layer will call to get / update the data it needs. This layer will generally either call a Database or some other system (eg: LDAP server, web service, or NoSql-type DB)

Controller Layer: Which will receive client requests.

In other words, you have a client-server architecture, with an n-layer pattern, where the angular (view layer) uses the MVVM pattern.

Observation:
Your Model you use may or may not come from your services. You may want to take the results your service gives you and manipulate them into a Model that's more specific to your medium (eg: a web page).

differentiate between database models (dao - data access object) and transfer model (dto - data transfer object)